# How Center Gtk Dialog on Parent Windows

Tags: c#, gtk#

The code:

```
    void btnSettings_Click(object obj, EventArgs args)
    {
        frmSettings dialogSettings = new frmSettings();
        dialogSettings.Modal = true;
        dialogSettings.TransientFor = this;
        dialogSettings.Parent = this;
        dialogSettings.ParentWindow = this.GdkWindow;
        dialogSettings.SetPosition(Gtk.WindowPosition.CenterOnParent);

        dialogSettings.Show();
    }
```

I tried TransientFor, Parent, ParentWindow properties but none of them force my dialog to be showed center on parent (caller) window.  Ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem. In frmSettings constructor I had a ShowAll before setting TransientFor.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to set the Dialog's parent in the constructor:

```
public MyDialog (Gtk.Window parent) 
         : base ("My title", parent, Gtk.DialogFlags.Modal, new object[0])
{
    this.Build();
}

public override void Dispose ()
{
    Destroy();
    base.Dispose();
}
```

And then call it from the parent window like so:

```
var dialog = new MyDialog(this);
try 
{
    var response = (ResponseType) dialog.Run();
    //handle response...
}
finally
{
    dialog.Dispose();
}
```